# Change input style if filled using a class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, if-statement

I found fiddle to change input style if filled. But it's using ID. I want to use class name. I used `document.getElementsByClassName()`, but it's not working. Anyone can help? Thanks.

Here is the code

html

`<input type="text" id="subEmail" onchange="checkFilled();"/>`

Javascript

```
function checkFilled() {
var inputVal = document.getElementById("subEmail");
if (inputVal.value == "") {
    inputVal.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
else{
    inputVal.style.backgroundColor = "";
}
}

checkFilled();
```

and here is the link to [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Xgfr/829/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)** returns array of dom elements so you need to use `inputVal[0]` instaed of `inputVal`

```js
function checkFilled() {
  var inputVal = document.getElementsByClassName("subEmail");
  if (inputVal[0].value == "") {
    inputVal[0].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  } else {
    inputVal[0].style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
}

checkFilled();
```

```html
<input type="text" class="subEmail" onchange="checkFilled();" />
```

> **Document.getElementsByClassName()** : Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names. When called on the document object, the complete document is searched, including the root node. You may also call getElementsByClassName() on any element; it will return only elements which are descendants of the specified root element with the given class names.

Taken from : **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)**

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("subEmail")
```

The above returns all the elements with same class name as an array. You probably need to get the first element in the array like

```
document.getElementsByClassName("subEmail")[0]
```

[**`UPDATED FIDDLE`**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Xgfr/912/)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to pass the reference of element for which event is invoked.

*HTML*

```
<input type="text" onchange="checkFilled(this);"/>
```

*Script*

```
function checkFilled(elem) {
    elem.style.backgroundColor = elem.value == "" ? "yellow" : "";
}
```

```js
function checkFilled(elem) {
  elem.style.backgroundColor = elem.value == "" ? "yellow" : "";
}

window.onload = function() {
  checkFilled(document.getElementsByClassName("subEmail")[0]);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="subEmail" onchange="checkFilled(this);" />
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the fiddle working http://jsfiddle.net/2Xgfr/913/

```
function checkFilled() {
    var inputVals = document.getElementsByClassName("subEmail");

for(var i=0; i<inputVals.length;i++){
    if (inputVals[i].value == "") {
        inputVals[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
    else{
        inputVals[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
    }
}

checkFilled();
```

And the html

```
<input type="text" id="subEmail" class="subEmail" onchange="checkFilled();"/>
```

I used a for cycle so you can have multiple field.